# como hacer un vinculo a una carpeta compartida

Tags: php, javascript, html5

estoy intentando hacer un *hipervinculo* en **html**, para abrir una carpeta compartida (abrirla con el **explorer.exe** de **Windows**) desde mi intranet, no se si se pueda lograr, porque he leído en varias paginas y en la mayoría dice que no se puede por temas de seguridad. solo encontré una pagina en la cual decía que se podía siempre y cuando estuvieran en la misma red (si se cumple esta condición)

este es el codigo que uso.

```
  <div class="card">
     <a class="card-footer clearfix small z-1" href='file:///\\mex\mon\kate\ka\files\'>
       <span class="float-left">Shared Folder</span>
       <span class="float-right">
         <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
       </span>
     </a>
     </div>
```

al darle click me sale este error en la consola

```
Not allowed to load local resource: file:///\\mex\mon\kate\ka\files\
```

Me explico mejor... lo que quiero es, por ejemplo como en cualquier navegador, que al descargar un archivo hay un *hipervinculo* que dice mostrar en carpeta, y al darle click , la abre y muestra todo lo que hay dentro

Answer (score 1):

primero no puedes acceder remotamente  desde una pagina web a un directorio local, claramente te lo dice aqui :

```
Not allowed to load local resource
```

traduccion: 
**No se permite cargar recursos locales**

la mejor opcion es crear un folder en tu servidor y agregar la ruta de tu folder donde tienes los archivos quieras mostrar igualmente puedes mostrar las carpetas de tu folder que quieres que sea vea.

**actualizacion**

primero: tu ruta esta mal no es asi deberia ser algo asi:

```html
<body>
 <div>
  <a href="C:\Users\sudhanshu\Pictures">Click here to open the folder
  </a>
 </div>
</body>
```

igualmente te sugiero leer [los permisos de chrome](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/114662?co=GENIE.Platform=Desktop&hl=en)

[como crear una carpeta compartida en una intranet](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/324067/how-to-set-folder-security-for-shared-folders)

**QUE TE RECOMIENDO YO?**

**crea un servidor root(principal) y despues hazlo visible a todas las computadoras de tu red(intranet) y listo.**

Comment: ya edite la pregunta para que me entiendas mejor.

Comment: @user80520 te refieres a la opcion de "show in folder" o "mostrar en  carpeta" de algunso navegadores?

Comment: Si, quiero hacer eso mismo. pero con una carpeta compartida en la red, no con la carpeta descargas.

Answer (score 1):

Si se puede, es una caracteristica propia de la suite SharePoint, y esta disponible desde hace muchos años, lamento decirte que ya no es compatiblle con chrome, pero si desde IE <= 11. y asi es el código.

`var crmfieldnameShare = "\\\\mex\\mon\\kate\\ka\\files"
var oShell = new ActiveXObject("Shell.Application");
oShell.Open(crmfieldnameShare);`

Comment: Ugh, ActiveX. Esto definitivamente ya no es viable en 2022.